# Select localization (language) Anylogic PLE

Tags: localization, anylogic

I downloaded Anylogic for Mac and I don't find how to change language. (I found Windows guide, but Mac settings doesn't have this setting) and looks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it at the Tools-> Preferences

(FYI AnyLogic does not navigate to these preferences if you use the standard Mac command of CMD + , to get to settings of any applications)

[image]

[image]